# how can i fix the 403 error in spotify api?

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, spotify

i'm creating a web app that tells any user their top artists/tracks on spotify.
If i log in with the account of the same clientId i'm using, it works. But if i login with another account it gives me this error:

[image: error header][image: error response]

There's something i don't quite understand... after this i registered the other user in my developer dashboard and now it works but how do i make it so anyone can access the app without me having to manually register their account?

here's my code which i took directly from spotify's official web api examples and made some changes:

*script.ts*

```
import { redirectToAuthCodeFlow, getAccessToken } from "./authCodeWithPkce";

const clientId = "*client id*";
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get("code");

if (!code) {
  redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId);
} else {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken(clientId, code);
  const profile = await fetchProfile(accessToken);
  populateUI(profile);
}

async function fetchProfile(code: string): Promise<UserProfile> {
  const result = await fetch(
    "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks?time_range=long_term&limit=10",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${code}` },
    }
  );

  return await result.json();
}

function populateUI(profile: UserProfile) {
  document.getElementById("displayName")!.innerText =
    profile.items[0].album.album_type;
}
```

*authCodeWithPkce.ts*

```
export async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId: string) {
  const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
  const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

  localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("response_type", "code");
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:3000/callback");
  params.append("scope", "user-top-read");
  params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
  params.append("code_challenge", challenge);

  document.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;
}

export async function getAccessToken(clientId: string, code: string) {
  const verifier = localStorage.getItem("verifier");

  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append("client_id", clientId);
  params.append("grant_type", "authorization_code");
  params.append("code", code);
  params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:3000/callback");
  params.append("scope", "user-top-read");
  params.append("code_verifier", verifier!);

  const result = await fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: params,
  });

  const { access_token } = await result.json();
  return access_token;
}

function generateCodeVerifier(length: number) {
  let text = "";
  let possible =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
}

async function generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier: string) {
  const data = new TextEncoder().encode(codeVerifier);
  const digest = await window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", data);
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(digest)]))
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=+$/, "");
}
```

How do i get rid of the 403 error without manually registering every user? Is there something i'm missing in the code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to request a quota extension to let everyone use your app, as you can [read here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/development-extended-quota-modes/).

Comment: @Ximzend oh... it says "Please note that we will not grant a quota extension for home automation, school, or hobby projects." and i needed it for a portfolio project so i guess i should drop the idea then cause there are no other ways, right? Thank you for the answer :)